# App script to Filter repeated DATA sets, but keep information that is new for each set

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script

Hi I currently have this App script code,

```
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("DataBase");
 var stmt = conn.createStatement();
 var temp_date_start = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1L4UrgCzwH2mZ7LBi7utiyzVqKkGKt32g3Akfs99OhHk').getSheetByName('_0_tbl_BankTracker_Rollup_Cross').getRange('J1').getValue();
 var startDate = new Date(temp_date_start);
 //calledstoredpro = "{?=call SP_Generate_BankTracker_WF_StagesReport()}";
  stmt.setQueryTimeout(0);
 stmt.setMaxRows(5000);
var results = stmt.executeQuery('call SP_Generate_BankTracker_WF_StagesReport');

var numCols = results.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
 
  
  var values = [];
  while (results.next()) {
    var temp = [];
      for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
      temp.push(results.getString(col + 1))
    }
    values.push(temp);
  }
  Logger.log(values)
 
  results.close();
  stmt.close();
    
  sheet.getRange('A1:X400').clearContent();
  
  sheet.getRange(5, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  results.close
}
```

it is creating repeated data sets EX: below

```
example 1020083 3   22  Hillside Park Units 3 & 4   315016  15  16  12612 test Avenue   NewYork, NY House   2021-04-27  2021-05-11      144956.14   38854   106102.14   69623.62    75332.52    1   0.15
example 1020083 3   22  Hillside Park Units 3 & 4   315016  15  16  12612 test Avenue   NewYork, NY House   2021-04-27  2021-05-11      144956.14   38854   106102.14   69623.62    75332.52    2   0.02
example 1020083 3   22  Hillside Park Units 3 & 4   315016  15  16  12612 test Avenue   NewYork, NY House   2021-04-27  2021-05-11      144956.14   38854   106102.14   69623.62    75332.52    3   0.12
example 1020083 3   22  Hillside Park Units 3 & 4   315016  15  16  12612 test Avenue   NewYork, NY House   2021-04-27  2021-05-11      144956.14   38854   106102.14   69623.62    75332.52    5   0.07
example 1020083 3   22  Hillside Park Units 3 & 4   315016  15  16  12612 test Avenue   NewYork, NY House   2021-04-27  2021-05-11      144956.14   38854   106102.14   69623.62    75332.52    6   0.06
example 1020083 3   22  Hillside Park Units 3 & 4   315016  15  16  12612 test Avenue   NewYork, NY House   2021-04-27  2021-05-11      144956.14   38854   106102.14   69623.62    75332.52    7   0.08
example 1020083 3   22  Hillside Park Units 3 & 4   315016  15  16  12612 testAvenue    NewYork, NY House   2021-04-27  2021-05-11      144956.14   38854   106102.14   69623.62    75332.52    8   0.03
example 1020083 3   22  Hillside Park Units 3 & 4   315016  15  16  12612 testAvenue    NewYork, NY House   2021-04-27  2021-05-11      144956.14   38854   106102.14   69623.62    75332.52    9   0.03
example 1020083 3   22  Hillside Park Units 3 & 4   315016  15  16  12612 test Avenue   NewYork, NY House   2021-04-27  2021-05-11      144956.14   38854   106102.14   69623.62    75332.52    11  0.03
example 1020083 3   22  Hillside Park Units 3 & 4   315018  15  18  12620 test Avenue   NewYork, NY House   2021-04-12  2021-04-30      149005.13   38854   110151.13   78508.41    70496.72    1   0.15
example 1020083 3   22  Hillside Park Units 3 & 4   315018  15  18  12620 test Avenue   NewYork, NY House   2021-04-12  2021-04-30      149005.13   38854   110151.13   78508.41    70496.72    2   0.02
example 1020083 3   22  Hillside Park Units 3 & 4   315018  15  18  12620 test Avenue   NewYork, NY House   2021-04-12  2021-04-30      149005.13   38854   110151.13   78508.41    70496.72    3   0.12
example 1020083 3   22  Hillside Park Units 3 & 4   315018  15  18  12620 test Avenue   NewYork, NY House   2021-04-12  2021-04-30      149005.13   38854   110151.13   78508.41    70496.72    5   0.07
example 1020083 3   22  Hillside Park Units 3 & 4   315018  15  18  12620 testAvenue    NewYork, NY House   2021-04-12  2021-04-30      149005.13   38854   110151.13   78508.41    70496.72    6   0.06
example 1020083 3   22  Hillside Park Units 3 & 4   315018  15  18  12620 test Avenue   NewYork, NY House   2021-04-12  2021-04-30      149005.13   38854   110151.13   78508.41    70496.72    7   0.08
example 1020083 3   22  Hillside Park Units 3 & 4   315018  15  18  12620 test Avenue   NewYork, NY House   2021-04-12  2021-04-30      149005.13   38854   110151.13   78508.41    70496.72    8   0.03
example 1020083 3   22  Hillside Park Units 3 & 4   315018  15  18  12620 test Avenue   NewYork, NY House   2021-04-12  2021-04-30      149005.13   38854   110151.13   78508.41    70496.72    9   0.03
example 1020083 3   22  Hillside Park Units 3 & 4   315018  15  18  12620 test Avenue   NewYork, NY House   2021-04-12  2021-04-30      149005.13   38854   110151.13   78508.41    70496.72    10  0.03
example 1020083 3   22  Hillside Park Units 3 & 4   315018  15  18  12620 test Avenue   NewYork, NY House   2021-04-12  2021-04-30      149005.13   38854   110151.13   78508.41    70496.72    11  0.03
```

Ive tried looking for a way to filter the Array and add the new information to the end of the matching data, but unable to get one that works.

Comment: So what exactly is your question here? How should the end result look like?

Comment: If you look at the data you see that the same address comes up multiple times with different values at the end EX: 1,0.15 and then 2,.02. was seeing if there is a way to sort by like addresses but add the two end values to the end to make up something like 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
15% 2% 12% 0% 7% 6% 8% 3% 3% 3% 3%              
15% 2% 12% 0% 7% 6% 8% 3% 3% , I should add that 4 will always be 0%

Comment: It looks like nobody understand you. Try to add to your question a sample of date that you want to get. Is it a table? Or a list of strings? I'm sure the task to group the data can be solvet pretty easy. But it's need to see how result should look like.

Answer (score 1):

What the 'matching data'? Some condition for every line? Of another array with the same length? To add where? At the end of every line?

For example:

```js
var a = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9]
]
console.log(a) // original array

var b = a.map(row => row.concat(['b']))
console.log(b) // added 'b' to every row

var c = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']
var d = b.map((row,i) => row.concat([c[i]]));
console.log(d) // added c[row] to every row

var e = d.map(row => (row[0]>1) ? row.concat(['yes']) : row.concat(['no']));
console.log(e) // added 'yes' or 'no' to every row based on first cell value
```